# PHP empty page on SQL query execution and bool(false) on var_dump

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, mariadb

I'm writing this PHP program to query the database for some values and display it. The problem is if I execute it, an empty page is shown. I tried `var_dump` on the result, it gives `bool(false)` But this query works perfect on standalone SQL.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

//Access local db with this script
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "dev";
$password = "somepassword";
$dbname = "dbname";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "with hours as (
  select 0 hr
  union all select hr + 1 where h < 23
);
select h.hr, count(e.eventID) as cnt
from hours h
left join events e 
  on e.timeStamp > now() - interval 1 day
  and hour(e.timestamp) = h.hr
group by h.hr;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo "";
if ($result) {
  while ($obj = $result -> fetch_object()) {
    printf("%s, ", $obj->cnt);
    echo mysqli_error($this->conn) ;
  }
  $result -> free_result();
}
else
{
  mysqli_error($conn);
}
echo "";
$conn->close();
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please do View Source ... on that web page before you decide you have no output.

Comment: You have a `;` at the end of your `cte` definition that should not be there.

Comment: Use multi_query for do what you want.

Comment: @simone If you are going to suggest this extremely dangerous function you better explain why. There's almost never any reason to use it.

Comment: @Dharman "extremely dangerous function" explain me why that's dangerous?

Comment: @simone It adds no value whatsoever and if misused in a way that you introduce SQL injection, it could do a lot of damage. If something brings no value, but only more risks it is dangerous.

Comment: @Dharman 
I don't agree, just check that the variables are completed and just not having to make an update there can be no damage to the DB

Comment: @Dharman but if you have reference i need to study :)

Comment: Thanks guys. Figured out the problem though.. Turned out my RDBMS didn't support Recursive CTEs. I changed my code and it's working fine now!